# Counting does not work properly in OpenMP

Tags: c, openmp, c89

I have the function

```
void collatz(int startNumber, int endNumber, int* iter, int nThreads)
{
    int i, n, counter;
    int isodd; /* 1 if n is odd, 0 if even */
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; i++)
    {
        counter = 0;
        n = i;
        omp_set_num_threads(nThreads);
        while (n > 1)
        {
            isodd = n%2;
            if (isodd)
                n = 3*n+1;
            else
                n/=2;
            counter++;
        }
        iter[i - startNumber] = counter;
    }
}
```

It works as I wish when running serial (i.e. compiling without OpenMP or commenting out `#pragma omp parallel for` and `omp_set_num_threads(nThreads);`). However, the parallel version produces the wrong result and I think it is because the `counter` variable need to be set to zero at the beginning of each for loop and perhaps another thread can work with the non-zeroed `counter` value. But even if I use `#pragma omp parallel for private(counter)`, the problem still occurs. What am I missing?

I compile the program as C89.

Comment: Try to add `private(counter, n, isodd)` to your OpenMP `parallel` directive...

Comment: This solves the problem. Please put it into an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your OpenMP parallel region, you are assigning values to the `counter`, `n` and `isodd` scalar variables. These cannot therefore be just `shared` as they are by default. You need to pay extra attention to them.

A quick analysis shows that as their values is only meaningful inside the parallel region and only for the current thread, so it becomes clear that they need to be declared `private`.

Adding a `private( counter, n, isodd )` clause to your `#pragma omp parallel` directive should fix the issue.